# How to bring up the compensation aspect in discussion with my boss?

Tags: management, salary, compensation

I joined this organisation from college and been here for 2 years now. Many folks who joined along with me have left. And the subsequent year graduates have been joining in with higher starting packages. 
Note - I've had regular appraisals but the difference remains.

All this while I have never brought up compensation/moving-up-the-ladder in one-on-one conversations with my boss. (These so far have been work-centric.)

How do I bring up compensation the next time?

Answer (score 2):

Your employer's goal is to keep you for the lowest possible salary for which you are willing to stay. Your goal is to maximize your benefits from your employer, wether that is salary/vacation days etc. is up to you.

Next time you have your annual review: first do the review as usual. Nearing the end of the review, when your boss usually says,

> "Do you have any questions?"

Tell him you think you deserve a raise **and tell him why**.

> "*Insert whatever you call your boss to his face*, I think I deserve a raise. I have been here for 2 years now and did 'x' and that added 'Y' revenue. Also I did 'a' and that saved 'b' time, thus saved us 'c' dollars".

Give him **reasons** why you should get a (bigger) raise rather than only saying your peers have higher salary and you working here for 2 years.

Comment: I'll add more context - I've add appraisals but the difference remains. Added to question